# Suppressing output from exec() calls in PHP

Tags: php

I have a number of command line scripts in PHP that use [exec()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) to perform tasks such as restarting services, loading MySQL timezone files, etc.  While exec() itself does not output anything to the screen, some of the commands I am running are forcing output that I can't seem to suppress (even with ob_start()/ob_end_clean()).  For example, the following would load timezone files into MySQL.  We run this periodically to make sure MySQLs timezone data is up to date:

```
 $command = 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql';
 exec($command, $output, $result);
```

In this example, I would expect all output from the command to be written into $output, but I still get the following output forced to the screen:

```
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh87' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh88' as time zone. Skipping it.
Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/Asia/Riyadh89' as time zone. Skipping it.
...
```

Is there any way to suppress this output?  Redirecting to /dev/null is not ideal as that would cause PHP to continue processing without waiting for the command to complete.

Thanks in advance,
~ JamesArmes

Comment: For those wondering why the example code isn't working, it's because only `stdout` is captured. The errors given are being written to `stderr`, which is not captured but rather dumped to the screen.

Comment: I came to this thread through google looking for a way to supress all output when running a PHP CLI script. My solution was to wrap the `exec()` call in `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Redirecting stderr alone should not influence where processing takes place, just make sure not to add an `&`. It should only run in the background if you redirect the output and make it run in the background.

Edit:

Cracked open cygwin, you need to redirect stderr for the first command, give this a try:

```
$command = 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo 2> /dev/null | mysql mysql';
exec($command, $output, $result);
```

Comment: This is not entirely true. The PHP manual means that if you simply use `&` without redirection, PHP will still hang. Redirection alone still does not cause it to run in the background.

Comment: Hmm indeed, that seems more plausible. I will correct my answer

Comment: Redirecting using
    $command = 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql 2> /dev/null';
still causes the same output.  However, calling my script like
    php mysql_timezones.php 2> /dev/null
properly suppress the output.  Is it possible to get the same results without calling my script in that fashion?

Comment: Try `&> /dev/null`. please note there is no space between `&` and `>`

Comment: I just figured this out and came here to post my findings, only to find that you beat me to it :-P It was indeed mysql_tzinfo_to_sql outputting the errors and not mysql.  Thanks to everyone who responded!

Comment: Return *The system cannot find the path specified.* on Windows.

Answer (score 12):

Just redirect `stderr` to `/dev/null`

```
$command = 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql 2>/dev/null';
```

or to `stdout`

```
$command = 'mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql mysql 2>&1';
```

Answer (score 4):

Redirecting to /dev/null does **not** cause PHP to stop waiting for the command. Adding a `&` *does* do this, you probably associate the two because the final `&` is often used in conjunction with a redirect.

In response to Yannick's (deleted) comment: it seems if you want to run something in the background in PHP, you *must* redirect as well as using `&`. **This does not mean that redirection alone causes it to run in the background.**

Comment: According to the PHP manual "If a program is started with this function, in order for it to continue running in the background, the output of the program must be redirected to a file or another output stream. Failing to do so will cause PHP to hang until the execution of the program ends."  Although it appears your are correct, PHP requires both a redirect and the background operator &

Comment: JamesArmes: that is precisely what the 2nd part of my answer was intended to explain

Answer (score 1):

According to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php you can assign this command's output to a variable.

You don't necessarily have to do anything with the variable, which means you are effectively suppressing output.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's what the $output variable in the exec() call is supposed to do (it's passed by reference).  I have tried using shell_exec() and it produces the same results.