# php: use exec command without output to CLI

Tags: php

I am migrating a set of php scripts from Window 2003 / PHP 5.2 to Windows 2012 R2 / PHP 5.6.7

In the scripts exec commands are used, for example to copy files. Commands could look like this:

```
exec ('copy "C:\ftp\suppliername\upload\*.*" c:\somefolder\  >> output.log');
```

You could argue that there are better ways to copy files, but I rather wouldn't like to rebuild these scripts right now.

The problem I have is that when there are no files to copy, the error "The system cannot find the file specified." is now shown, while this wan't the case on the old server.

If you just execute the copy command on the command line, the output looks like this:

```
The system cannot find the file specified.
        0 file(s) copied.
```

This is the same as what gets written to output.log
So apparently the "0 file(s) copied" is getting suppressed somewhere, but not the error.

So my question is, how do I get rid of the error on the commandline? I thought it would be some configuration in php.ini, but after comparing the php.ini from the old and the new server, I couldn't find any essential differences.

I've tried a few things to suppress the error, but with no success:

- Adding a @ to the exec command
- Adding ob_start() and ob_end_clean() before and after the command

Edit: please do not flag as a duplicate. I did see that question before asking my question. the answers given there do not solve my issue. The main question is, why was it working before, you would think that it should still be possible to get it working the same way without modifications to the scripts.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Suppressing output from exec() calls in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606943/suppressing-output-from-exec-calls-in-php)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding "2>&1" to your command.

```
exec ('copy "C:\ftp\suppliername\upload\*.*" c:\somefolder\  >> output.log 2>&1');
```

This should redirect the error output to output.log

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that this string is being printed to stderr.
You could try to replace your STDERR as described in the post https://stackoverflow.com/a/3823015/146003.

The essential part of the post consists of the lines:

```
fclose(STDERR);
(...)
$STDERR = fopen('error.log', 'wb');
```

You can then get rid of error.log. Although I didn't try, you could try to open `NIL` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/313115/146003)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are redirecting the output of the copy command to a text file, so it will not be ouput to console.

Do this way instead:

```
exec ('copy "C:\ftp\suppliername\upload\*.*" c:\somefolder\', $output);

var_dump ($output);
```