# php exec not working in a function?

Tags: php, exec

Using a wamp / php 5.3 I have a weird behavior I'd like your opinion about...

I need to execute some external/shell commands but when I pack them in function the exec() doesn't seem to work anymore...

Exemple:
If I do something like:

```
<?php 
/// some stuff

$getAppCmd = $CLI_CMD." -q -f ".$CLI_REQ_PATH."\getApp.py";
exec($getAppCmd, $apps, $rt);
print_r($apps);

/// other stuff
?>
```

==> It works just fine :)

BUT, if I try to achieve something more reusable:

```
<?php
// Some stuff

function getApp(){
    $getAppCmd = $CLI_CMD." -q -f ".$CLI_REQ_PATH."\getApp.py";
    exec($getAppCmd, $apps, $rt);       
    print_r($apps);
    return $apps;
}
$list = getApp();
print_r($list);

//other stuff
?>
```

==> I'm printing nothing Array() Array()

Am I missing something ?

I've been through some several thread but couldn't find something to guide me, return is supposed to work even if I'm returning an array, and the command is the same inside & outside the function...

I don't get it and need bit of your help.

Thanks !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Suppressing output from exec() calls in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606943/suppressing-output-from-exec-calls-in-php)

Comment: you can use `glob`  http://php.net/manual/ru/function.glob.php

Answer (score 1):

You're executing the command `dirC:\temp` instead of `dir C:\temp`, the space is missing here.

```
$path = "C:\temp";
$cmd = "dir ".$path;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, actually this was for illustration purpose ^^ Sorry if that spread some doubt. I'm editing the code with the true command it will be more relevant