# Unable to suppress output of dos2unix command in jenkins console output

Tags: php, jenkins, dos2unix

I have a Jenkins triggered project which has the following command wrapped in a PHP exec -

```
$dos2unix = exec("dos2unix ".$filePath);
```

It shows the following unwanted command output in the Jenkins console output and clutters the screen -

```
dos2unix: converting file /home/jenkins/deployment_beta/phing/scratchpad/adserver/app/webroot/openx/lib/OA/Dal/Delivery/mysql.php to UNIX format ...
dos2unix: converting file /home/jenkins/deployment_beta/phing/scratchpad/adserver/app/webroot/openx/lib/OA/Dal/Maintenance/Statistics/Common.php to UNIX format ...
```

I tried wrapping the command in an ob_start() and ob_end_clean() and also directed the output to /dev/null -

```
ob_start();
$dos2unix = exec("dos2unix ".$filePath." > /dev/null");
ob_end_clean();
```

But, I am still getting the same in console output.

*Note - If I trigger the build manually in command line, I do not see this undesired output, regardless of whether I have directed the output to /dev/null or wrapped in output buffer statements.*

I have read [Suppressing output from exec() calls in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1606943/suppressing-output-from-exec-calls-in-php?rq=1) but could not solve the problem.

Answer (score 3):

dos2unix prints its messages to stderr. To redirect them you need to use 2> instead of >.

```
$dos2unix = exec("dos2unix ".$filePath." 2> /dev/null");
```

Another option is to use option -q. With -q dos2unix will not print messages and it will not return an error code when something goes wrong.

```
$dos2unix = exec("dos2unix -q ".$filePath.");
```

Comment: Is there some way I can collect the output in either case (regardless of error), but suppress the console output at the same time, or am I contradicting myself?

Comment: I would like to collect the output in $dos2unix and be able to handle error/success.

Comment: I did this finally - `$returnVal = exec("sudo dos2unix 2>&1 ".$filePath,$outputArray,$result); if(count($outputArray)>0)
  {
   $finalLine = $outputArray[count($outputArray)-1];
   $success = $result==0 && ($finalLine == "dos2unix: converting file ".$filePath." to UNIX format ...");
  }` May be I should rely only on the $result.

Comment: I never used Jenkins.